# Spectra of Methylene Blue

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy, photochemistry

**Does the spectrum of Methylene Blue change on prolonged exposure to light?**
I've studied about the photochemical reactions and about energy transfer reactions. Methylene Blue is a triplet sensitizer used for the production of singlet oxygen through energy transfer reaction, **can this formed singlet oxygen attack methylene blue?** Why is leuco(colorless) form of Methylene Blue is formed?

One more thing is still confusing me, while the energy transfer reaction we say that energy is transferred from sensitizer to another molecule, but which form of energy is transferred is the light or heat energy, if it is light energy which is transferred then the light of same wavelength is transferred which caused the excitation of the sensitizer?

If anyone can please help me through these confusions...

Comment: That MB "attacks itself" via the production of singlet oxygen makes much sense. It should be what is done in a large number of studies in conjunction with (photo)catalysts in the field of photocatalytic cleaning, or TiO2 solar cells. Type MB photodegradation and you will find a multitude of references. Unfortunately, at a first glance I did not see anything really accessible.